# Remove sun glare using GIMP

Tags: gimp, glare

How can the glare from the sun in the upper right part of this photo be removed using Gimp?

[image: sun glare]

Comment: The technique to do it is by increasing local contrast… but I can't see a way to do that in Gimp. I tried it in Photoshop using mainly Dehaze then Burned the highlights locally & finally Sharpened the trees to the right [settings on 'kill' to emphasise everything] . I hope someone can figure an equivalent for Gimp. Example - https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMK4c.jpg

Comment: When you say "local' contrast, do you mean that only a selected part of the image is affected? And if so, how do you select that part?

Comment: Local contrast is adjusting micro-tonalities between otherwise similar areas. Exaggerating the differences. You could try to mask out an area, but as most of the image suffers the same issue, I didn't bother for the example above.

Comment: For the future, it is easier to remove lens flares with a lens hood than with Gimp. When I find myself “saving” pictures, I assume my limitations are when I press the shutter not when I sit at the computer.

Comment: I agree. This was taken with my phone so no lens hood, though now that I think about it maybe there is an attachment.

Comment: If you've got no lens hood, hold your hand up to shade it.

Comment: Actually, now that you've put this bug in my ear, I'm going to try designing one for the Pixel 4 in Autocad and then 3d print it.

Comment: Lens hoods work best when the inside face is totally non-reflective, otherwise you can create more problems than you solve. 1st party [OEM] are worth the money here, 3rd party [& by extrapolation DIY] are not worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GMIC](https://gmic.eu/) is a powerful GIMP plugin with a lot of filters for enhancing local contrast.
You could also duplicate the layer, increase the contrast such that the top right is fixed, and manually erase the other parts of the layer with a large soft eraser.